# pandas: contradictory output using sort_values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am seeing differences in my output when using sort_values. As an example I have written the code in 3 different ways, whose output should all be the same unless I have misunderstood something. I am using pandas 0.25.3. Can someone explain why this is happening?

```
df1 = df.loc[:, ['A', 'B', 'ref']].sort_values(by='ref').reset_index(drop=True)
df1 = df1.loc[df['ref'].isin(['r1','r2','r3'])]

df2 = df.loc[:, ['A', 'B', 'ref']]
df2 = df2.loc[df['ref'].isin(['r1','r2','r3'])]

df3 = df.loc[df['ref'].isin(['r1','r2','r3']), ['A', 'B', 'ref']].sort_values(by='ref').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Below output for df1 is incorrect, while the other 2 are correct:

```
cond=((df1['A']-df1['A'].shift(-1))*(df1['B']-df1['B'].shift(-1))<0)
x = cond.groupby(df1['ref']).any()
print(x)

ref
r1   True
r2   True
r3   True
dtype: bool

cond=((df2['A']-df2['A'].shift(-1))*(df2['B']-df2['B'].shift(-1))<0)
x = cond.groupby(df2['ref']).any()
print(x)

ref
r1   True
r2   False
r3   True
dtype: bool

cond=((df3['A']-df3['A'].shift(-1))*(df13['B']-df3['B'].shift(-1))<0)
x = cond.groupby(df3['ref']).any()
print(x)

ref
r1   True
r2   False
r3   True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: What is the DF my friend? No one can know if its incorrect or not, maybe there is some missunderstanding with the signs or parenthesis

Comment: Apologies. I cannot share the exact DF for security purposes. I will attempt to recreate a dummy DF for the purposes of this question and get back to you